# Specify security configuration in Amazon EMR from a CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

When creating an EMR cluster, you can specify a security configuration which I created prior. How do I specify this option from JSON cloudformation template?

I am referencing here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html#cfn-emr-cluster-additionalinfo

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the [`SecurityConfiguration`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_RunJobFlow.html#EMR-RunJobFlow-request-SecurityConfiguration) Request Parameter for the [`RunJobFlow`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_RunJobFlow.html) API does not have a corresponding property on the [`AWS::EMR::Cluster`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html) CloudFormation Resource, so it seems that this feature is not (yet) officially supported in CloudFormation. This feature was added on [Sep 21 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/amazon-emr-now-supports-data-encryption-for-apache-spark-tez-and-hadoop-mapreduce/), and there is typically a lag between new feature announcements and their corresponding support in existing CloudFormation resources.

As a workaround, you could create a [Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that calls the `RunJobFlow` API directly.

Comment: Good to know. What if I use this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-security-configuration.html within the Configurations property in AWS::EMR::Cluster, will that work?

Comment: I don't think it will work- `Configurations` and `SecurityConfiguration` are two different properties.

Comment: Still new to this and trying to figure this out. I see a `CreateSecurityConfiguration` Action. How would would go about using that then, what's the purpose for it under EMR? I found it by going to the Amazon EMR Configuration from here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-emr-cluster-configuration.html

Comment: Also, can you elaborate with an example in your answer how you would use the custom resource to accomplish this within the `AWS::EMR::Cluster`? In my case I just want to specify the security config name.